# Collection in custom control does not update view wpf

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

Can anybody with some customcontrol experience help????

can you spot why my collection does not update ?

Basically I have 2 listboxes and when I move items between the two
the count of the items does not go down.(Property does not update)

Debugging the custom control the properties within the control are correct ,
but when it's propagated to the view that uses the custom control it doesnt!.

Link where you can download project.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmyWRgk_dFxGaohoQA_v-aulUOE

I am so close but so far.
I did not want to post lots of code and get no reply.
Project is tiny.

I have tried setting binding by default but does not work.

Suggestions?

**CustomControl  (2 listboxes and buttons to move items left and right)**

**generic.xaml**

```
    <ListBox Name="PART_lstLeft" 
          MinHeight="200"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LeftItems, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedIndex="0" />

     same for the right listbox
```

**--END OF xaml**

**CustomControl code**

```
    public MultipleListControl()
    {
        LeftItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        RightItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftItemsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("LeftItems",
                    typeof(IEnumerable<object>),
                    typeof(MultipleListControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable<object> LeftItems
    {
            get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(LeftItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LeftItemsProperty, value); }
    }


      public static readonly DependencyProperty RightItemsProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register("RightItems",
           typeof(IEnumerable<object>),
           typeof(MultipleListControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable<object> RightItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(RightItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    etc.... rest irrelevant
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> availableCustomers;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> AvailableCustomers
    {
        get { return availableCustomers; }
        set
        {
            availableCustomers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AvailableCustomers");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> selectedCustomers;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> SelectedCustomers
    {
        get { return selectedCustomers; }
        set
        {
            selectedCustomers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomers");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:CustomerSelectorViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
  </Window.Resources>        

         <multipleList:MultipleListControl  
                    Name="MultipleListControl1" 
                   LeftItems="{Binding Source=
                   {StaticResource ViewModel},
                   Path=AvailableCustomers,Mode=TwoWay}"

                   RightItems="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel},
                   Path=SelectedCustomers,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

first your list box ; `ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding LeftItems,`

second your view ; `LeftItems="{Binding AvailableCustomers` if your viewmodel is set in the datacontext

should have a look at another code because seems you are not doing it right
[custom](http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CBR/CBR/Components/Controls/RatingControl.cs) and the solution to use it [solution](http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl)

Comment: thanks for your time I would be grateful if you could spare few minutes to clear this up as it's been holding me for a bit now.I am reading about custom controls etcs.. but in the meantime I need to sort this one out  the items are bound but the collection does not update

Comment: Tried you changes but still does not work ,collection does not update .any ideas?

Comment: how is defined the ViewModel? why static ? ?   LeftItems="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel ???

Comment: it was     
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModels:CustomerSelectorViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>                                                          LeftItems="{Binding Source=
                   {StaticResource ViewModel},
                   Path=AvailableCustomers,Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: undo the the view change; seems ok; do you have any binding errors in the output tab of visual when you run it ?

Comment: I do not see any errors in out put tab.Too much trouble to download the noddy project and check ?I would really appreciate